# How dependant is breezjs serverside contexprovider to entityframework?

Tags: breeze

I am building a WebApi for a CMS that has its own data provider. No DBContext or entity framework involved.

I have previously used breeze as it being such a breeze to map the server side model to the client:)

I have wondering if I can extend my code or breeze in a way such I get all the stuff from brezejs for free.

What I have to work with is the following Interfaces that I have made implementations for based on the data provider from the CMS.

```
public interface IC1Repository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T Add(T item);
    void Remove(T item);
    bool Update(T item);
}
```

Its generic, so thats not going to work on the client.

I can generate a context class i guess that holds all the types exposed.

```
public class mycontext
{
public IC1Repository<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public IC1Repository<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public IC1Repository<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

What would my next steps be to get this workign with breeze. Are there any interfaces i can implement such it mimics the DbContext. Can i maybe crate my custom DbSet that do not talk with a database, but just is a implementation of my IC1Repository above?

Any advices thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked their website and docs?  Have you looked at any of the samples they provide?  It is not dependent on ef and they have plenty of examples to prove it

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I have read the docs. I want the same behavior as I get when I use EF and breeze together, but I cant use EF in this project, so I need to convert my repository to something breeze WebApi can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the **`ContextProvider`** which is the base class of the `EFContextProvider`.

That has the same semantics and same base behavior as the `EFContextProvider` but it doesn't use EF.

Check out [the "No DB" sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb) which uses the `ContextProvider` to manage queries and saves to an in-memory "database".

Ignore the fact that this class sits in a DLL with references to EF. I realize that is annoying. But your project will compile and run just fine when there are no EF assemblies around. You can delete all the EF stuff if you used NuGet to get the Breeze.WebApi.dll.